# Drupal 7 Alchemy php skd error

Tags: sdk, drupal-7

I'm having difficulty getting the Alchemy module working with a drupal 7 site.  I keep getting the error:

"The Alchemy module requires the Alchemy SDK. Use the PHP version of the SDK. Download the SDK here.

Download the files and place them in a folder named "AlchemyAPI" under the alchemy module directory."

I have downloaded these files and tried them in several different locations.  Currently they are in sites/all/modules/alchemy/AlchemyAPI/modules/ but I keep getting the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the files in the following location.
**sites/all/modules/alchemy/AlchemyAPI/**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried them there and am still getting the error.  Is there anything I should do in terms of re-installing the module after I move these files?

Comment: try downloading the php files form here http://www.alchemyapi.com/tools/ and put them in the AlchemyAPI folder and try again.

Comment: I tried that and no luck.  I had previously installed SEO Tools (which is a huge package) and then uninstalled it.  Could this be causing an issue?  (I've made sure that alchemy does have all it's dependencies).